# how to change button color with jQuery on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change a button colour when clicked using jQuery.

I want the button to change from blue to grey when clicked.

so far I have this code

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVPrq/)

```
$(".vote-number").hide();
$(".vote-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.vote-number').finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried to change the colour at all.

Comment: 'how to change background-color using jquery' in google search would give you the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/dVPrq/7/

```
$(".vote-number").hide();

  $(".vote-btn").click(function(){
      $(this).css({'background':'grey'}).next('.vote-number').finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
  });
```

Newer version of the above fiddle which restores the blue color after fadeout: http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/dVPrq/9/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding a CSS class with jQuery, which keeps the styling aspect of it in the CSS, rather than putting it directly in the logic.

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvFy7/1/)**</kbd>

***JS***

```
$(".vote-btn").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('clicked')
        .next('.vote-number')
        .finish()
        .show()
        .fadeOut(5000);
});
```

***CSS***

```
.vote-btn {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.vote-btn.clicked {
    background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the background color of the button you clicked as below

```
 $(".vote-btn").click(function(){
          $(this).css({"background-color":"grey"});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".vote-btn").click(function(){
          $(this).next('.vote-number').finish().show().fadeOut(5000);
          $(this).css('background','grey');
      });
```

To convert the clicked Button.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dVPrq/8/)